# GLMM with many and highly correlated features

Tags: r, correlation, mixed-model, pca, glmm

Lately I came upon a very interesting project, which also made me thinking since it was the first time for me to work on such data.

So, I have 2-level data, with 60 participants having 2-3 measurements each, allocated (almost balanced) in two groups, say Y variable. This Y is also my outcome. Then, there are also about 350 features.

Therefore, the goal is to predict the Y class based on the 350 features.

**Problem**: I have around 180 (not independent) observations, and 350 variables. Obviosuly this will not work... So somehow they have to be reduced

**Possible solution** : These 350 features are highly correlated in groups, meaning that they can form clusters which give similar information. If we were talking about independent data, then possible solution would be, say PCA, and then building the prediction model with a GLM based on these PCA features (although I never tried something like that, I see it is usual).

**However**,   Now that ultimately the goal is to use a GLMM, how can this be done ? Can you do PCA (or any variable reduction technique) in 2-level data ? And if yes, can you point me out where to learn about it?

If this is not possible, can you suggest something that you would do in this case ?

P.S. Since we are talking about a prediction model, is it still valid to assess prediction accuracy with AUC under GLMM ?

Thanks

Comment: if your goal is only prediction, why not simply use a RF?

Comment: @FlorianHartig Actually this is what i am working on right now...I am trying to reduce te number of predictors, using `findCorrelations()` from `caret` package, and then build a random forest...Because the more i think about it, the more difficutl it seems to use any of the glm models....